# Print PDF from FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is there the way to print pdf document from flex?

Answer (score 1):

For screen capturing,simple tables and text [Alivepdf](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org) will do. [PurePdf](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/) for nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a project that makes possible print preview but it also includes PDF preveiw and generation (PDF print). You can try it yourself at http://blog.kreatx.com/2011/11/11/flex-printing-print-preview-pdf-generation/ 
there you can find the source as well